# How to merge two hashes that have same keys in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a two hashes that should have same keys like:

```
a = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
b = {a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}
```

And I want to sum up each values like this:

```
if a.keys == b.keys
  a.values.zip(b.values).map{|a, b| a+b}
end
```

But this code doesn't work if the order of keys are different like `b = {a: 2, c: 4, b: 3}`.

How can I write the code taking into account about order of keys?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`Hash#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) or [`Hash#merge!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21):

```
a = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
b = {a: 2, c: 4, b: 3}
a.merge!(b) { |k, o, n| o + n }
a # => {:a=>3, :b=>5, :c=>7}
```

The block is called with key, old value, new value. And the return value of the block is used as a new value.

Comment: I like #merge with block. If I get a chance, I use it.

Comment: Getting this error:

[!] undefined method `+' for #<Hash:0x007fcea7130330>

Comment: @HenningHall, https://ideone.com/yKrqLc Seems like you're using old version of ruby where `Hash#merge` does not exist. Not sure since which version it's available, but according to documentation, [it should be there for 1.8.6+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

Comment: i am struggle with my case how to do it it plz help me if anyone knows.                          1)a = {"Additional Options"=>{"Break Fast"=>100.0,"Lunch"=>300.0}, "Discount"=>{}, "Coupon"=>{"cou"=>10}}          2)                                                                                  b = {"Additional Options"=>{"Break Fast"=>100.0}, "Discount"=>{}, "Coupon"=>{"cou"=>10.0}} My Expectation is Like This
=>{"Additional Options"=>{"Break Fast"=>200.0,"Lunch"=>300.0}, "Discount"=>{}, "Coupon"=>{"cou"=>10.0}

Comment: @giridharan, Please post a separated question.

Comment: My question limits reached

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Active Support (Rails), which adds `Hash#transform_values`, I really like this easy-to-read solution when you have `n` hashes:

```rb
hashes = [hash_1, hash_2, hash_3] # any number of hashes
hashes.flat_map(&:to_a).group_by(&:first).transform_values { |x| x.sum(&:last) }
```